# Unregister a PRISM Region from the RegionManager

Tags: c#, prism, region

Is there a way to un-register a region from the RegionManager?

With

```
RegionManager.SetRegionName(myRegion, regionName);
RegionManager.SetRegionManager(myRegion, myRegionManager);
```

I do register a region at the RegionManager.

But what, if I need to remove that registration (in order to register the exact same region again)?

===================

This is my situation:

I have an instance `myView` that registers a UI control (a DependencyObject) `myRegion` as a region by using:

```
RegionManager.SetRegionName(myRegion, regionName);
RegionManager.SetRegionManager(myRegion, myRegionManager);
```

When `myView` is instantiated, also the local region manager object `myRegionManager` is instantiated.

Then I need to again create the instance `myView`, which again makes this registration.

Hence, the new instance `myView` also instantiates a new local region manager `myRegionManager`, which of course has no regions associated with.

Then, the call to `RegionManager.SetRegionName(...)` and `RegionManager.SetRegionManager(...)` succeedes, but if I then try to access the local region manager `myRegionManager` by using

```
IRegion region = myRegionManager.Regions[regionName];
```

I am getting an `RegionUpdateException`!

If I place

```
string name = RegionManager.GetRegionName(myRegion);

IRegionManager regionManager = RegionManager.GetRegionManager(myRegion);
```

in front of the registration, both fields are empty by the first instantiation of `myView`, but they do have values during the second instantiation of `myView`.

But since both the `myRegion` and the `myRegionManager` also get newly instantiated together with `myView` I expect the name and region manager also to be empty before calling the second registration.

Comment: So you have a `myView` that sets a region name on a `myRegion` and then you create a new `myView` and a new `myRegion` and the new `myRegion` still has the region name of the old one, correct? Are you sure you're really looking at the new one? if you recreate the `myView` first, it might use the old `myRegion`or the old `myRegionManager`or both...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegionManager`'s `Regions`-Property to remove the region by name:

```
public interface IRegionManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a collection of <see cref="IRegion"/> that identify each region by name. You can use this collection to add or remove regions to the current region manager.
    /// </summary>
    IRegionCollection Regions { get; }

    [...]
}
```

and

```
public interface IRegionCollection : IEnumerable<IRegion>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    [...]

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a <see cref="IRegion"/> from the collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="regionName">Name of the region to be removed.</param>
    /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if the region was removed from the collection, otherwise <see langword="false"/>.</returns>
    bool Remove(string regionName);

    [...]
}
```

Comment: I extended my post to provide more information about my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it sounds like you need to have multiple instances of the same View which has a region defined in it, and be able to inject other views inside those respective regions.  Is this correct?

Check out the documentation on ScopedRegions: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/50-ComposingtheUserInterface.md#creating-multiple-instances-of-a-region

You can also watch this Pluralsight course that shows you how to use ScopedRegions: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/prism-showing-multiple-shells/table-of-contents